# Java HtmlUnit Ajax call never get rendered in the HtmlPage

Tags: java, ajax, screen-scraping, htmlunit

I am attempting to scan a page using HtmlUnit 2.31.  I am simply getting an HtmlPage by URL.  However, there seems to be some AJAX calls kicked off by the page (no user interaction).  I need to wait for the calls to finish and be "rendered" so I can see the values.  Here is my code:

```
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
        webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
        webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
        webClient.setJavaScriptTimeout(10000);

        String itemsForSalePageURL = "https://miami-dade.realtaxdeed.com/index.cfm?zaction=AUCTION&Zmethod=PREVIEW&AUCTIONDATE=07/24/2018";
        HtmlPage previewItemsForSalePage = webClient.getPage(itemsForSalePageURL);

        final JavaScriptJobManager tmpJobManager = previewItemsForSalePage.getEnclosingWindow().getJobManager();
        while(tmpJobManager.getJobCount()>0){
            System.out.println("javascript is still running...");
        }

        boolean doneLoading = false;
        while(!doneLoading){
            System.out.println("checking if page is done loading...");
            List<HtmlDivision> loadingElements = previewItemsForSalePage.getByXPath("//div[@class = 'Loading']");
            if(loadingElements.isEmpty()){
                doneLoading = true;
            }
        }

        String contents = previewItemsForSalePage.asXml();

        System.out.println( "Run complete." );
    }
```

The problem is: the `while(!doneLoading)` loop becomes an infinite loop.  The classes that my xpath is searching for never evaluates to anything besides "loading".

One area I am interested in is:

```
        <div id="Area_C" class="Auct_Area" ref="Y" arid="C">
          <div tabindex="0" class="Loading"></div>
        </div>
```

In Chrome, this evaluates to

```
<div id="Area_C" class="Auct_Area" ref="N" arid="C">
    <div tabindex="0" id="AITEM_1159704" class="AUCTION_ITEM PREVIEW adc-spacer" aid="1159704" rem="0" isset="1" data-test="check"><div tabindex="0"><div tabindex="0" class="adc-tab"><div tabindex="-1" class="banner-left-side"></div>This item has <strong>complimentary</strong> photos, valuation reports and title information.<div tabindex="-1" class="banner-right-side"></div></div><div tabindex="0" class="AUCTION_STATS"><div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSGA ASTAT_LBL">Auction Status</div><div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSGB Astat_DATA">Canceled per Bankruptcy</div><div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSGC ASTAT_LBL"></div> <div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSGD Astat_DATA"></div><div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSG_SOLDTO_Label ASTAT_LBL"></div><div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSG_SOLDTO_MSG Astat_DATA"></div></div><div tabindex="0" class="AUCTION_DETAILS adc"> <table class="ad_tab" tabindex="0"><tbody><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Auction Type:</th><td class="AD_DTA">FORECLOSURE</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row" aria-label="Case Number">Case #:</th><td class="AD_DTA"> 2008-069895-CA-01</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Final Judgment Amount:</th><td class="AD_DTA">$567,016.30</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Parcel ID:</th><td class="AD_DTA"> <a href="http://www.miamidade.gov/propertysearch/#/?folio=0420360070830" onclick="return showExitPopup();" target="_blank">04-2036-007-0830</a></td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Property Address:</th><td class="AD_DTA">618 W 65 DR</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row"></th><td class="AD_DTA">HIALEAH, FL- 33012</td></tr> <tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Assessed Value:</th><td class="AD_DTA">$131,793.00</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Plaintiff max bid:</th><td class="AD_DTA ASTAT_MSGPB">$279,450.00</td></tr></tbody></table></div></div> </div><div class="AUCTION_ITEM_SPACER">&nbsp;</div><div tabindex="0" id="AITEM_1160530" aria-label="Auction Details" class="AUCTION_ITEM PREVIEW" aid="1160530" rem="0" isset="1"><div class="AUCTION_STATS"><div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSGA ASTAT_LBL">Auction Sold</div><div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSGB Astat_DATA">07/24/2018 09:07 AM ET</div><div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSGC ASTAT_LBL">Amount</div> <div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSGD Astat_DATA">$198,200.00</div><div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSG_SOLDTO_Label ASTAT_LBL">Sold To</div><div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSG_SOLDTO_MSG Astat_DATA">3rd Party Bidder</div></div><div class="AUCTION_DETAILS"><table class="ad_tab" tabindex="0"><tbody><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Auction Type:</th><td class="AD_DTA">FORECLOSURE</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row" aria-label="Case Number">Case #:</th><td class="AD_DTA"> 2012-007563-CA-01</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Final Judgment Amount:</th><td class="AD_DTA">$123,600.66</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Parcel ID:</th><td class="AD_DTA"> <a href="http://www.miamidade.gov/propertysearch/#/?folio=3069350010170" onclick="return showExitPopup();" target="_blank">30-6935-001-0170</a></td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Property Address:</th><td class="AD_DTA">26711 SW 133 CT</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row"></th><td class="AD_DTA">MIAMI, FL- 33032</td></tr> <tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Assessed Value:</th><td class="AD_DTA">$104,378.00</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Plaintiff max bid:</th><td class="AD_DTA ASTAT_MSGPB">$190,539.81</td></tr></tbody></table></div> </div><div class="AUCTION_ITEM_SPACER">&nbsp;</div><div tabindex="0" id="AITEM_1156810" aria-label="Auction Details" class="AUCTION_ITEM PREVIEW" aid="1156810" rem="0" isset="1"><div class="AUCTION_STATS"><div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSGA ASTAT_LBL">Auction Status</div><div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSGB Astat_DATA">Canceled per County</div><div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSGC ASTAT_LBL"></div> <div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSGD Astat_DATA"></div><div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSG_SOLDTO_Label ASTAT_LBL"></div><div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSG_SOLDTO_MSG Astat_DATA"></div></div><div class="AUCTION_DETAILS"><table class="ad_tab" tabindex="0"><tbody><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Auction Type:</th><td class="AD_DTA">FORECLOSURE</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row" aria-label="Case Number">Case #:</th><td class="AD_DTA"> 2013-006996-CA-01</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Final Judgment Amount:</th><td class="AD_DTA">$1,060,190.67</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Parcel ID:</th><td class="AD_DTA"> <a href="http://www.miamidade.gov/propertysearch/#/?folio=3350330550030" onclick="return showExitPopup();" target="_blank">33-5033-055-0030</a></td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Property Address:</th><td class="AD_DTA">17321 SW 93 AVE</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row"></th><td class="AD_DTA">PALMETTO BAY, FL- 33157</td></tr> <tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Assessed Value:</th><td class="AD_DTA">$276,458.00</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Plaintiff max bid:</th><td class="AD_DTA ASTAT_MSGPB">Hidden</td></tr></tbody></table></div> </div><div class="AUCTION_ITEM_SPACER">&nbsp;</div><div tabindex="0" id="AITEM_1150473" aria-label="Auction Details" class="AUCTION_ITEM PREVIEW" aid="1150473" rem="0" isset="1"><div class="AUCTION_STATS"><div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSGA ASTAT_LBL">Auction Status</div><div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSGB Astat_DATA">Canceled per Order</div><div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSGC ASTAT_LBL"></div> <div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSGD Astat_DATA"></div><div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSG_SOLDTO_Label ASTAT_LBL"></div><div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSG_SOLDTO_MSG Astat_DATA"></div></div><div class="AUCTION_DETAILS"><table class="ad_tab" tabindex="0"><tbody><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Auction Type:</th><td class="AD_DTA">FORECLOSURE</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row" aria-label="Case Number">Case #:</th><td class="AD_DTA"> 2013-009405-CA-01</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Final Judgment Amount:</th><td class="AD_DTA">$161,175.75</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Parcel ID:</th><td class="AD_DTA"> <a href="http://www.miamidade.gov/propertysearch/#/?folio=0821280140050" onclick="return showExitPopup();" target="_blank">08-2128-014-0050</a></td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Property Address:</th><td class="AD_DTA">13247 ASWAN RD</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row"></th><td class="AD_DTA">OPA-LOCKA, FL- 33054</td></tr> <tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Assessed Value:</th><td class="AD_DTA">$88,602.00</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Plaintiff max bid:</th><td class="AD_DTA ASTAT_MSGPB">Hidden</td></tr></tbody></table></div> </div><div class="AUCTION_ITEM_SPACER">&nbsp;</div><div tabindex="0" id="AITEM_1159431" aria-label="Auction Details" class="AUCTION_ITEM PREVIEW" aid="1159431" rem="0" isset="1"><div class="AUCTION_STATS"><div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSGA ASTAT_LBL">Auction Sold</div><div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSGB Astat_DATA">07/24/2018 09:14 AM ET</div><div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSGC ASTAT_LBL">Amount</div> <div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSGD Astat_DATA">$390,200.00</div><div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSG_SOLDTO_Label ASTAT_LBL">Sold To</div><div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSG_SOLDTO_MSG Astat_DATA">3rd Party Bidder</div></div><div class="AUCTION_DETAILS"><table class="ad_tab" tabindex="0"><tbody><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Auction Type:</th><td class="AD_DTA">FORECLOSURE</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row" aria-label="Case Number">Case #:</th><td class="AD_DTA"> 2014-012973-CA-01</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Final Judgment Amount:</th><td class="AD_DTA">$255,004.82</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Parcel ID:</th><td class="AD_DTA"> <a href="http://www.miamidade.gov/propertysearch/#/?folio=0141210071790" onclick="return showExitPopup();" target="_blank">01-4121-007-1790</a></td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Property Address:</th><td class="AD_DTA">3321 FROW AVE</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row"></th><td class="AD_DTA">MIAMI, FL- 33133</td></tr> <tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Assessed Value:</th><td class="AD_DTA">$199,959.00</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Plaintiff max bid:</th><td class="AD_DTA ASTAT_MSGPB">$287,550.00</td></tr></tbody></table></div> </div><div class="AUCTION_ITEM_SPACER">&nbsp;</div><div tabindex="0" id="AITEM_1145542" aria-label="Auction Details" class="AUCTION_ITEM PREVIEW" aid="1145542" rem="0" isset="1"><div class="AUCTION_STATS"><div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSGA ASTAT_LBL">Auction Status</div><div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSGB Astat_DATA">Canceled per Bankruptcy</div><div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSGC ASTAT_LBL"></div> <div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSGD Astat_DATA"></div><div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSG_SOLDTO_Label ASTAT_LBL"></div><div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSG_SOLDTO_MSG Astat_DATA"></div></div><div class="AUCTION_DETAILS"><table class="ad_tab" tabindex="0"><tbody><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Auction Type:</th><td class="AD_DTA">FORECLOSURE</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row" aria-label="Case Number">Case #:</th><td class="AD_DTA"> 2014-020812-CA-01</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Final Judgment Amount:</th><td class="AD_DTA">$294,642.58</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Parcel ID:</th><td class="AD_DTA"> <a href="http://www.miamidade.gov/propertysearch/#/?folio=3050290190190" onclick="return showExitPopup();" target="_blank">30-5029-019-0190</a></td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Property Address:</th><td class="AD_DTA">15900 SW 105 AVE</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row"></th><td class="AD_DTA">MIAMI, FL- 33157</td></tr> <tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Assessed Value:</th><td class="AD_DTA">$153,877.00</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Plaintiff max bid:</th><td class="AD_DTA ASTAT_MSGPB">Hidden</td></tr></tbody></table></div> </div><div class="AUCTION_ITEM_SPACER">&nbsp;</div><div tabindex="0" id="AITEM_1144806" class="AUCTION_ITEM PREVIEW adc-spacer" aid="1144806" rem="0" isset="1" data-test="check"><div tabindex="0"><div tabindex="0" class="adc-tab"><div tabindex="-1" class="banner-left-side"></div>This item has <strong>complimentary</strong> photos, valuation reports and title information.<div tabindex="-1" class="banner-right-side"></div></div><div tabindex="0" class="AUCTION_STATS"><div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSGA ASTAT_LBL">Auction Status</div><div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSGB Astat_DATA">Canceled per Order</div><div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSGC ASTAT_LBL"></div> <div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSGD Astat_DATA"></div><div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSG_SOLDTO_Label ASTAT_LBL"></div><div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSG_SOLDTO_MSG Astat_DATA"></div></div><div tabindex="0" class="AUCTION_DETAILS adc"> <table class="ad_tab" tabindex="0"><tbody><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Auction Type:</th><td class="AD_DTA">FORECLOSURE</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row" aria-label="Case Number">Case #:</th><td class="AD_DTA"> 2015-002717-CA-01</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Final Judgment Amount:</th><td class="AD_DTA">$500,378.48</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Parcel ID:</th><td class="AD_DTA"> <a href="http://www.miamidade.gov/propertysearch/#/?folio=3020030381200" onclick="return showExitPopup();" target="_blank">30-2003-038-1200</a></td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Property Address:</th><td class="AD_DTA">19522 NW 77 CT</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row"></th><td class="AD_DTA">HIALEAH , FL- 33015</td></tr> <tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Assessed Value:</th><td class="AD_DTA">$273,509.00</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Plaintiff max bid:</th><td class="AD_DTA ASTAT_MSGPB">Hidden</td></tr></tbody></table></div></div> </div><div class="AUCTION_ITEM_SPACER">&nbsp;</div><div tabindex="0" id="AITEM_1155118" aria-label="Auction Details" class="AUCTION_ITEM PREVIEW" aid="1155118" rem="0" isset="1"><div class="AUCTION_STATS"><div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSGA ASTAT_LBL">Auction Sold</div><div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSGB Astat_DATA">07/24/2018 09:20 AM ET</div><div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSGC ASTAT_LBL">Amount</div> <div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSGD Astat_DATA">$373,100.00</div><div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSG_SOLDTO_Label ASTAT_LBL">Sold To</div><div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSG_SOLDTO_MSG Astat_DATA">3rd Party Bidder</div></div><div class="AUCTION_DETAILS"><table class="ad_tab" tabindex="0"><tbody><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Auction Type:</th><td class="AD_DTA">FORECLOSURE</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row" aria-label="Case Number">Case #:</th><td class="AD_DTA"> 2015-004160-CA-01</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Final Judgment Amount:</th><td class="AD_DTA">$650,255.11</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Parcel ID:</th><td class="AD_DTA"> <a href="http://www.miamidade.gov/propertysearch/#/?folio=3049090040080" onclick="return showExitPopup();" target="_blank">30-4909-004-0080</a></td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Property Address:</th><td class="AD_DTA">15495 SW 13 TER</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row"></th><td class="AD_DTA">MIAMI, FL- 33194</td></tr> <tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Assessed Value:</th><td class="AD_DTA">$267,671.00</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Plaintiff max bid:</th><td class="AD_DTA ASTAT_MSGPB">$339,375.00</td></tr></tbody></table></div> </div><div class="AUCTION_ITEM_SPACER">&nbsp;</div><div tabindex="0" id="AITEM_1155459" aria-label="Auction Details" class="AUCTION_ITEM PREVIEW" aid="1155459" rem="0" isset="1"><div class="AUCTION_STATS"><div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSGA ASTAT_LBL">Auction Status</div><div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSGB Astat_DATA">Canceled per Order</div><div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSGC ASTAT_LBL"></div> <div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSGD Astat_DATA"></div><div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSG_SOLDTO_Label ASTAT_LBL"></div><div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSG_SOLDTO_MSG Astat_DATA"></div></div><div class="AUCTION_DETAILS"><table class="ad_tab" tabindex="0"><tbody><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Auction Type:</th><td class="AD_DTA">FORECLOSURE</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row" aria-label="Case Number">Case #:</th><td class="AD_DTA"> 2015-005595-CA-01</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Final Judgment Amount:</th><td class="AD_DTA">$217,737.00</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Parcel ID:</th><td class="AD_DTA"> <a href="http://www.miamidade.gov/propertysearch/#/?folio=0140010210019" onclick="return showExitPopup();" target="_blank">01-4001-021-0019</a></td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Property Address:</th><td class="AD_DTA">6261 TAMIAMI CANAL RD</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row"></th><td class="AD_DTA">MIAMI, FL- 33126</td></tr> <tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Assessed Value:</th><td class="AD_DTA">$153,080.00</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Plaintiff max bid:</th><td class="AD_DTA ASTAT_MSGPB">Hidden</td></tr></tbody></table></div> </div><div class="AUCTION_ITEM_SPACER">&nbsp;</div><div tabindex="0" id="AITEM_1151163" aria-label="Auction Details" class="AUCTION_ITEM PREVIEW" aid="1151163" rem="0" isset="1"><div class="AUCTION_STATS"><div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSGA ASTAT_LBL">Auction Status</div><div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSGB Astat_DATA">Canceled per Order</div><div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSGC ASTAT_LBL"></div> <div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSGD Astat_DATA"></div><div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSG_SOLDTO_Label ASTAT_LBL"></div><div tabindex="0" class="ASTAT_MSG_SOLDTO_MSG Astat_DATA"></div></div><div class="AUCTION_DETAILS"><table class="ad_tab" tabindex="0"><tbody><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Auction Type:</th><td class="AD_DTA">FORECLOSURE</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row" aria-label="Case Number">Case #:</th><td class="AD_DTA"> 2015-022277-CA-01</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Final Judgment Amount:</th><td class="AD_DTA">$374,062.43</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Parcel ID:</th><td class="AD_DTA"> <a href="http://www.miamidade.gov/propertysearch/#/?folio=3040280070030" onclick="return showExitPopup();" target="_blank">30-4028-007-0030</a></td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Property Address:</th><td class="AD_DTA">6020 SW 92 AVE</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row"></th><td class="AD_DTA">MIAMI, FL- 33173</td></tr> <tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Assessed Value:</th><td class="AD_DTA">$208,500.00</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Plaintiff max bid:</th><td class="AD_DTA ASTAT_MSGPB">Hidden</td></tr></tbody></table></div> </div><div class="AUCTION_ITEM_SPACER">&nbsp;</div> 
</div>
```

I am not sure what else to try at this point.  I have tried changing the BrowserVersion.  I have tried increasing the JavaScriptTimeout.  I tried using the NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController.  I even wait until all javascript is done processing.  I think I am missing some fundamental piece of understanding.  Can someone please fill me in.

Comment: Will have a look at this later today. In between you can try the latest snapshot and do not set setThrowExceptionOnScriptError to false. Maybe there is a js error that stops the execution before the ajax request. Another option is to use a WebProxy like Charles and have a look at the real wire conversation (and compare it with real browsers). Maybe you can see if all the ajax requests are processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here comes the workaround

```
String url = "https://miami-dade.realtaxdeed.com/index.cfm?zaction=AUCTION&Zmethod=PREVIEW&AUCTIONDATE=07/24/2018";

try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_60)) {
    webClient.setWebConnection(new FalsifyingWebConnection(webClient) {
        @Override
        public WebResponse getResponse(WebRequest webRequest) throws IOException {
            if (webRequest.getUrl().getPath().endsWith("jquery-1.6.1.min.js")) {
                String jQuery = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("jquery-1.6.1.js"));
                return createWebResponse(webRequest, jQuery, "application/javascript");
            }
            return super.getResponse(webRequest);
        }
    });

    HtmlPage previewItemsForSalePage = webClient.getPage(url);
    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(1000);

    System.out.println("----------------");
    System.out.println(previewItemsForSalePage.asText());
}
```

And here some notes:

- by using FalsifyingWebConnection you can intercept and manipulate the request and the response if you like
- be careful with this while statements without a timeout, many pages are using some kind of heartbeat; you while will never stop

At least here I got the same content as in real browsers.

Comment: RBRi, thanks for this response!  I am still at work.  I will try it later today.

Comment: I gave the changes a try.  They work perfectly.  HtmlUnit is a great tool.  Thank you very much for your assistance.  It is greatly appreciated. Keep up the great work. 
 I am marking this answer as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have done a quick check, this is an issue with jQuery 1.6.1 (see [issue 1835](https://sourceforge.net/p/htmlunit/bugs/1835/)). Because this only happens with the minimized version of jQuery this is really hard to fix (had to be done in Rhino at last). Any help is welcome....

Comment: Thanks for looking into this RBRi.  There doesn't appear to be any feasible work around for this from what I read. I can't control what js dependencies that webpage loads.  This sounds very tricky to fix within HtmlUnit.  Do you think it is feasible to download the source and place a hack that searches for jquery-1.6.1.min.js., prevents it from loading, and loads the non-minified version form a cdn instead?  This would be locally only of course.  OR should I give up and use another framework?

Comment: Good point, i think there is way to implement your workaround (using a local jQuery) without too much hacking. Will provide a sample impl as part of the issue. But later today....

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks.  After some research last night, I realized there really isn't any alternative to HtmlUnit.  It's a pretty awesome tool.  I look forward to your response.